# Migrating C#.NET App from Windows to OSX (Windows Forms)

Tags: winforms, macos, mono, monodevelop

I have a C#.NET Windows Forms project which compiles, builds and runs without any problems on Windows. Now I'm trying to migrate it to OSX using Mono. The project compiles and builds, but I get an exception (see attached image). When I double-click one of the entries in the stack trace, it says that the file couldn't be found. Does this mean that I forgot to install something when I installed Mono (i.e. something related to support for Windows.Forms) ????

[image]

Any help is appreciated - thank you!!

Comment: Just compiling is not enough. http://www.mono-project.com/Guide:_Porting_Winforms_Applications You might start from there, but the best way is to rewrite the UI using MonoMac/Xamarin.Mac. The WinForms port to non-Windows platforms is not at production quality yet.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think NotifyIcon is supported on OS X: [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=434754)