# Migrating C#.NET App from MS Visual Studio 2012 to MonoDevelop on Windows

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio, monodevelop

I have a MS Visual Studio 2012 C#.NET WinForms project which compiles, builds and runs fine on Windows.

I want to move the project to MonoDevelop (on Windows). Once I have it compiled and running without problems on Windows, I want to try and build it in Mono on OSX.

Besides containing .cs files, the solution/project also contains and forms/designs. A form/design comes as a set of files:

```
FileName.cs
FileName.Designer.cs (Code generated by Windows Form Designer)
FileName.resx (Embedded Resource)
```

What are the correct steps for migrating a MS Visual Studio 2012 C#.NET WinForms project to MonoDevelop on Windows ??

Comment: fair warning: mono is weird

Comment: possible duplicate of [Migrating C#.NET App from Windows to OSX (Windows Forms)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737457/migrating-c-net-app-from-windows-to-osx-windows-forms)

Comment: This might be useful as well: [When using the latest Monodevelop and VS 2012 RC to share code I get problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11049049/when-using-the-latest-monodevelop-and-vs-2012-rc-to-share-code-i-get-problems)